# Fill a group of textboxes with values for editing in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 groups of 5 textboxes representing telephone Numbers 1,2,...5 and fax numbers 1,2,...5 respectively. The requirement is to fill each group of textboxes with data from an associative array. How can i fill textboxes 1 and 2 from group telephone and textboxes 1, 2, 3 from group fax leaving the other textboxes empty?

Example of generated textboxes:

Telephone Numbers:
textbox 1 
textbox 2
textbox 3 
textbox 4
textbox 5

Fax Numbers:
textbox 1 
textbox 2
textbox 3 
textbox 4
textbox 5

```
    <?php
        echo '<table width="100%" class="table table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="docList">';
        echo '<tbody>';

            $listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet = clients::recupereListDocPourProjet($PROJET_ID);

            $telFax_provided = clients::recupereListDocClientTerminerPourProjet($CLIENT_PROJET_ID);

            $nombreTextbox = "";
            $iDossiers = 0;
            while($iDossiers < count($listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet))
            {
                foreach($telFax_provided as $eachTelFaxProvided)
                {
                    if($eachTelFaxProvided['DOC_ID']==$listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_ID'])
                    {

                        ??

                    }
                }
                echo('<br>');


                $nombreTextbox = $listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet [$iDossiers]['DOC_NUM'];
                $iDos = 0;
                while($iDos < $nombreTextbox )
                {
                    $counte = $iDos+1;
    ?>              
                    <tr>
                        <td>
    <?php                   
                            echo $listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet [$iDossiers]['DOC_NOM'].' '.$counte;
                            echo "<br>";
    ?>                          
                            <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel[<?php echo [$iDossiers]?>]['tel_id']" style="width:100%;">
                            <input type="text" id="fax" name="fax[<?php echo [$iDossiers]?>]['fax_id']" >
    <?php                       
                        echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                $iDos ++;
                }
            $iDossiers ++;
            }
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';

    ?>
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Looking at your code it seems a "textbox" is a [HTML input element of type text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text). You can use the attribute "value" to assign a value to such an element: `<input type="text" value="012345">`.

Comment: i tried to echo the value but it doesnt work

Comment: foreach($telFax_provided as $eachTelFaxProvided)
{
  if($eachTelFaxProvided['DOC_ID']==$listTelFaxTextboxesPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_ID'])
{
$tel_num = $eachDocTerminer['TEL_NUM'];
echo $eachDocTerminer['DOC_ID'];
echo('<br>');
echo $eachDocTerminer['TEL_NUM'];
echo('<br>');           
}}

and in the text value: 
<input type="text" id="tel" name="tel[<?php echo [$iDossiers]?>]['tel_id']" value="<?php echo $tel_num ; ?>"style="width:100%;">

it doesnt work, the tel num gets repeated